# How to call a function as an argument

Tags: common-lisp

I have the following code just to get the hang of a few things:

```
(defun ordered (numbers)
  (sort numbers #'<))

(defun median (ordered)
  (princ ordered))
```

I want to call the function ordered, as an argument in median. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you're trying to do this below. I renamed the parameter to median just for clarity, but the last statement shows how to call median with the ordered function as an argument.

```
(defun ordered (numbers)
  (sort numbers #'<))

(defun median (numbers)
  (princ numbers))

(median (ordered (list 5 3 4)))
```

The output of this statement is just:

```
(3 4 5)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help :) It seems in all the things I have learnt I have either forgotten or didn't learn the really basic information.